# appending lists of list with column values from an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have 3 arrays of 3x1 in a list, that I want to append to a list of lists, where each list is a single row 1x3 from each array.

for example, convert this:

```
[array([['0.6913'],
       ['0.7279'],
       ['0.724']], dtype=object), 
array([['0.6943'],
       ['0.7206'],
       ['0.714']], dtype=object), 
array([['0.6456'],
       ['0.7447'],
       ['0.7378']],dtype=object)]
```

to:

```
   [[0.6913, 0.6943, 0.6456],
    [0.7279, 0.7206, 0.7447],
    [0.724, 0.714, 0.7378]]
```

How can I do this? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack):

```py
import numpy as np

a = [
    np.array([['0.6913'], ['0.7279'], ['0.724']], dtype=object),
    np.array([['0.6943'], ['0.7206'], ['0.714']], dtype=object),
    np.array([['0.6456'], ['0.7447'], ['0.7378']], dtype=object),
]

np.hstack(a)
```

```
array([['0.6913', '0.6943', '0.6456'],
       ['0.7279', '0.7206', '0.7447'],
       ['0.724', '0.714', '0.7378']], dtype=object)
```

To convert to `float` use [`.astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)

```
np.hstack(a).astype(float)
```

```
array([[0.6913, 0.6943, 0.6456],
       [0.7279, 0.7206, 0.7447],
       [0.724 , 0.714 , 0.7378]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I learned something new today!

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could help.